# Is there reliable information on the prevalence of debug backdoors in software?

Tags: software, backdoor

Developers sometimes forget to turn off the debug features of the software they ship: [CWE-489](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/489.html)

It is said [here](http://blog.erratasec.com/2012/05/bogus-story-no-chinese-backdoor-in.html) that

> About 20% of home routers have a backdoor in them, and 50% of
>   industrial control computers have a backdoor.

But this assertion is not backed. Is there any other information available, or study made, about the prevalence of those backdoors in code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a reliable, scientific study as to the prevalence of backdoors in proprietary devices or SCADA/industrial control systems.  A search of JSTOR turns up nothing interesting (although, if someone else wants to double check, please let me know if you find something!) Thus, the number you reference is likely just speculation or based on anecdotal evidence.

That said, I do not believe this number is without some justification.  When using closed-source products, there's always the risk of a backdoor.  As the article points out, many are unintentional and are a result of developers wanting to quickly test the system without dealing with access controls.

However, the main theme of the article has to do with international intelligence organizations inserting backdoors into products intended for vital roles in another nation, in this case, SCADA systems in China meant for use in the USA.   In those instances, it can be *assumed* that such backdoors are in place.  When the USA ships Boeing airplanes to China, for example, they have famously come laden with numerous and redundant bugs throughout the chassis.

So, my short answer is, one can never be sure about backdoors in closed-source products.  On the home router, it may be best to flash to an open source firmware if you share these concerns.  But as to scientifically quantify the rate that devices are backdoored; I believe that hasn't been done and would be challenging to do in a statistically significant fashion.

Comment: I suppose the question is: do you need evidence that there are back doors, or evidence that there isn't, to determine trust.